# Burton Elementary Number Theory Revised Printing Section 9.1 Problem 2(a)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

*Burton Elementary Number Theory* Revised Printing Section 9.1 Problem 2(a) asks

For an odd prime $p$, prove that the quadratic residues of $p$ are congruent modulo $p$ to the integers $1^2, 2^2, 3^2, \ldots, \left(\frac{p - 1}{2}\right)^2$.

I am wondering if my proof is too vague and how I might make it better. Here is what I have:

Given an odd prime $p$, since every square is congruent modulo $p$ to one of $1^2, 2^2, \ldots, (p - 1)^2$ and $x^2 \equiv_p (p - x)^2$, by definition of quadratic residue, the quadratic residues of $p$ are congruent modulo $p$ to $1^2, 2^2, 3^2, \ldots, \left(\frac{p - 1}{2}\right)^2$.